# How to handle google maps api with out Internet in javascript

Tags: java, javascript, google-maps, jsp, user-interface

In our application we are using google maps api in jsp. Recently we identified in offline mode google maps js files are not loading and due to this other application related javascript files are stopped working.

Below are the ways I tried to resolve but unfortunately both are not working.

I moved my javascript from script tag to window page load but in this case the web browser is keep on rotating to load google maps script and to avoid this i set window time out(don't know exactly what it does). Even after time out also the browser is keep on rotating.

From:

```
<script
    src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&v=2&key=<%=mapKey%>"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
```

To:

```
function loadScript() {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = 'http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&v=2&key=<=%googleMapKey%>';
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  }
  window.onload = loadScript;
```

or

```
 $(function(){
        var timeoutId;
        timeoutId = window.setTimeout(function() {
            alert("Script Error!");
            //document.getElementById("myFrame").value = "";

        }, 20);
        var url = 'http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&v=2&key=<%=googleMapKey%>&callback=initialize';
        $.getScript(url, function(){ window.clearTimeout(timeoutId) });
    });
```

Really Appreciate if you can help me to handle this.

Comment: So do you want to use Google Maps in offline mode or just ignore the fact that it won't load?

Comment: I just want to continue other stuff in my jsp if it won't load.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could have the script loaded asynchronously via something like jQuery's getScript and then only execute your functions to load the google map stuff if the ajax call succeeds, if not, then continue on as normal without google maps stuff.

```
$.getScript( "http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&v=2&key=<%=googleMapKey%>&callback=initialize" )
  .done(function( script, textStatus ) {
    //load your google maps stuff
  })
  .fail(function( jqxhr, settings, exception ) {
    //hide placeholder for google maps / display error
});
```

(taken shamelessly from http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/ )

Comment: If I add above code snippet, web browser is keep on rotating.

Comment: Did you include the jQuery library in your code? Reference it before the above script like [this](http://jquery.com/download/#using-jquery-with-a-cdn).